# Get deep of a logic hierarchical structure

Tags: algorithm, record, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I have the data that represent hierarchical structure

```
|id|parent_id|data|
|1 |0        |cat1|
|2 |1        |cat2|
|3 |4        |cat3|
|4 |5        |cat4|   
|5 |0        |cat5|
```

That represent a hierarchical structure like this

```
1
|_2
|
5
|_4
  |_3
```

I need to implement some function or algorithm prefirible that allowme to 
create a hierarchical structure and get the **deep** of every node according to the logic structure. i mean get this information.

```
|id|parent_id|data|deep|
|1 |0        |cat1|0   |
|2 |1        |cat2|1   |
|3 |4        |cat3|2   |
|4 |5        |cat4|1   |
|5 |0        |cat5|0   |
```

Comment: What is deep of every record? Is it where tree can collapse?

Comment: Sorry i edit a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you've `node` with reference of `parent_node` then function `deep` could implemented as follows:

(Each node has id & data property)

```
int deep(node *n) {
    /* deep of root node is zero and that's our base case */
    if(n->parent_node.id == 0)
        return 0;
    return 1 + deep(n->parent_node);
}
```